# Do TFS Power Tools have any use in a VSTS-only scenario?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (and 2017) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).  I've noticed that I have the TFS Power Tools 2015 installed.  I am not using a TFS server anywhere nor am I likely to.  I'm wondering if I have any use for the power tools.  If not I'd like to uninstall them, just to have less cruft on my system.

Do the TFS Power Tools have any use in a VSTS scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS Power Tools include few tools and features, the most is irrelevant if you use VSTS, but some of the features still relevant:

- Check-in policies
- Storyboard Shapes
- Team Explorer Enhancements
- Windows PowerShell Cmdlets
- Windows Shell Extensions

If you not using this features you can uninstall it.
See [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) all details about TFS
 Power Tools and decide whether to keep it or remove it.

Answer (score 2):

### No not really to he honest.

The Check-in policies have been rolled into the product as of Visual Studio 2017. The team explorer enhancements too. The cmd-lets were never good to begin with, there's better alternatives in the [vsts-cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cli), [tfx-cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli) and [vsteam](https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam). And the [Windows Shell Extensions ship stand-alone](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention).